# Arc Drawable For Android Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I Need Help Creating an Arc Shape for Android Layout. I don't Need Code for this. If it's possible using shapes it will be great.

Example Usage:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/arc">
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout Should Like like this:
[image: layout arc drawable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the requirements for the shape of your arc are but you could achieve the above using a VectorDrawable:

`arc.xml` (in res/drawables/)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="223dp"
        android:height="237dp"
        android:viewportWidth="223"
        android:viewportHeight="237">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#757491"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M44,3 L0,228 C0,228 68,239 114,236 C151,236 223,221 223,221 L197,0
C197,5.68434189e-14 158,11.7434499 120,11 C82,10.2565501 44,3 44,3 Z" />
</vector>
```

Then as you have above:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/arc">
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that there are platform limitations when using VectorDrawables (API 21+) or you can use the Support Library to backport the functionality if you need to support earlier API levels.

How did I make the above code?  I traced out the shape in a vector package (Sketch/Illustrator/etc) and exported it as an `svg` file.  I then used the very handy tool at https://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ to convert it to VectorDrawable code.

If you need something more dynamic then I personally would just create a custom `Drawable` in Java and draw using `Path` on `Canvas` but you indicate you don't want to do this.